# TV изображение не позволяет выбрать файл

Tags: cms, modx

Создаю TV дополнительное поле изображение, прикрепляю его к определенному шаблону. 
Создаю страницу, выбираю нужный шаблон, перехожу на вкладку Дополнительные поля (TV). В поле где надо выбрать изображение такая возможность отсутствует. В чём может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема рушилась выбором источника медиа файлов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте по отдельности - поудалять кеш, посмотреть логи в консоли браузера, выставить compress_js и compress_css в сист.настройках в ноль.
Какая версия MODX? попробуйте обновить заново хотя бы той же версией.
Какие компоненты стоят? Иногда, например, Ace нехорошо влияет на всю систему в целом.
Я встречал пару раз такое, что TV не отображается, каждый раз решалось по-разному, но все склоняется к тому, что где-то что-то криво настроено/установлено.